# ng-required not working properly on select the value from dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive, angular-validation

I have Date of birth drop down field,from that i selected the month,date and year values from dropdown.After selecting them as the error message showing previously it worked fine.
my code for that:

```
                    <div class="form-group form-inline">
                      <span for="">Birthday</span>
                      <div class="row panel-body">
                        <select name="month" id="month" class="custom-select col-xs-4" ng-model="dateOfBirth.month" onchange="call()" required >
                          <option value="">Month</option>
                          <option value="1">Jan</option>
                          <option value="2">Feb
                          <option value="3">Mar</option>
                          <option value="4">Apr</option>
                          <option value="5">May</option>
                          <option value="6">Jun</option>
                          <option value="7">Jul</option>
                          <option value="8">Aug</option>
                          <option value="9">Sep</option>
                          <option value="10">Oct</option>
                          <option value="11">Nov</option>
                          <option value="12">Dec</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="day" id="day" class="custom-select col-xs-4" ng-model="dateOfBirth.day" onchange="call()" required>
                          <option value="">Day</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="year" id="year" class="custom-select col-xs-4" ng-model="dateOfBirth.year" onchange="call()" required>
                          <option value="">Year</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <div ng-show="(frm.month.$touched || frm.day.$touched || frm.year.$touched)">
                        <span style="color:red" ng-show="((frm.month.$touched && frm.month.$error.required) || (frm.day.$touched && frm.day.$error.required) || (frm.year.$touched && frm.year.$error.required))">Date is required</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Error getting even if i select the values from the dropdown.

[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Thanks@ Souhali Ben Slimene  date is required (it is in red color).and in the consloe ng-invalid and ng-invalid-required after selecting the vlaues

Comment: could you edit your post and add the call() function!!

Comment: that will get the dates in months and years  .nothing is there

Comment: your are using ng-model you dont need to get them you already have them in your $scope !!

Comment: Yes i am using ng-model @SouhailBenSlimene

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143397/discussion-between-souhail-ben-slimene-and-ajay).

Comment: updated question with screenshot and have a look at that @SouhailBenSlimene